# Reducing memory grant waits in development environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I've got a query which waits a long time for memory grants, even though it's the only query running at the time. The query plan is at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkNF4LF6K

I cannot change the query content, but I can do anything with my server running locally (developer edition, so all features available).

I've tried enabling the resource manager already, hoping to force a quicker turnaround with the memory requests:

```
ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP "default" with (
  REQUEST_MEMORY_GRANT_TIMEOUT_SEC = 1,
  REQUEST_MAX_MEMORY_GRANT_PERCENT = 5)
```

But this didn't seem to have any impact.

I don't believe I can add indexing on a function in SQL Server, although that would be great.

What else can I change from the server side to make a query like that execute in a reasonable time?

Comment: "I don't believe I can add indexing on a function in SQL Server" no index is used if you use a function on the predicate like this `REPLACE(MEDICARE_NO, ' ', '')`.  Have you seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216931/warning-about-memory-excessive-grant-in-the-query-plan-how-to-find-out-what)? since it's a dev environment, try running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;` (do not use it in production environment), then try executing your query again to see if the execution plan changes.

Comment: @Ronaldo Unfortunately since I can't change the query, the linked question doesn't help me much - I can already see in my plan where the memory requests come from. Dropping the cache didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: How wide (column count) is the table? How selective is the query - are the filtering status codes to be found in majority or small subset of rows? Have you checked if you have accurate statistics on every column mentioned after the WHERE clause? I'd update statistics WITH FULLSCAN. I don't think it will solve your problem fully, but it is good start. What resources does your dev. SQL have since it struggles with granting 320MB of RAM? I woild check sys.dm_os_memory_clerks to check what is RAM used for. You can paste the results to your question.

Comment: @sranda ~80 columns. Status filters out very few rows. The partial string match will still run on 99% of the table and return at most 5 rows out of cm_patient (which has 200k rows total).

Comment: I would try few things: 1) To have an index on patient_id in cm_patient table (cannot tell what's clustering key in cm_patient table). 2) Since you cannot change the query, I would try to fight back with indexes. I would index for STATUS_CODE and try to run. I would try to add Surname, FIRST_NAME into the index and try to run it (both having surname, firstname) before status_code and another attempt: have that 2 columns after status_code in the index column ordering. You could also try to include MEDICARE_NO (not as a key column) to said index.

Comment: Huge guess here: can you rename your table, create a copy of it with little data, run your query, if it performs well without requesting a big memory grant, you could get the generated execution plan and try to [Apply a Fixed Query Plan to a Plan Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/apply-a-fixed-query-plan-to-a-plan-guide?view=sql-server-ver15). Also, what's your sp_configure option (minimum memory per query (KB))?

Answer (score 1):

Since your original question got closed out as a dupe, re-posting my answer here (with additional information) so it's preserved for other people experiencing similar issues:

You appear to be having a [cardinality estimate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) issue which is resulting in the unnecessary memory grant to occur (as Martin pointed out). You should always use your execution plans as a comparison even if they both are doing the same operations, because the runtime statistics may be different between the *slow* and *fast* run, which appears to be the case here.

You can observe the cardinality estimate issue you're experiencing in this example by looking at the **clustered index scan** operation on the right side of your execution plan. It is showing **Actual Number of Rows** is 5, but the plan's **Estimated Number of Rows** is over 7,000. This is a significant overestimate that results in the query requesting and waiting for much more memory than it needs. (Sometimes you'll the see the opposite occur, where the cardinality estimate is an underestimate, and under requests memory and / or generates a less efficient execution plan as a result.)

Your issue likely results from [non-sargable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) and hard to optimize predicates in your `WHERE` clause, most likely these predicates `WHERE (REPLACE(MEDICARE_NO, ' ', '') LIKE '111111111%') AND (STATUS_CODE Not in ('D', 'X','I','Z'))`. Using functions in predicates can result in cardinality estimate issues like you're currently seeing. So replacing () the `REPLACE()` function with a different solution would probably help fix your issue. You can either store the data already staged with spaces replaced or add a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) to your table that applies the `REPLACE()` function. You can even make it a persisted computed column and index it, since the `REPLACE()` function is deterministic.

Your other predicate `AND STATUS_CODE Not in ('D', 'X','I','Z'))` could also be better rewritten to maximize performance. `NOT IN` is an inequality operator and makes it difficult for the engine to optimize for. You're better off using `IN` and listing the values that are valid, which would be an equality operation then. Additionally the `IN` clause is just *syntactical sugar* for multiple `OR` clauses. Sometimes that also throws off the optimizer and you can try replacing them with using a `UNION` clause instead, for each value from your `IN` clause. Of course that would require you to repeat your query multiple times, so it hurts maintainability and readability a little bit, but most times you can refactor the core part of your code to a CTE first then use a `UNION` against that CTE for each value in the `IN` clause.

But I'd recommend focussing on eliminating your use of the `REPLACE()` function in your `WHERE` clause first. My instincts would say that's your bigger issue here. You can quickly prove it out too by testing with selecting your data into a temp table first, with `REPLACE(MEDICARE_NO, ' ', '') AS SomeColumn` as a column you select into the temp table. Then use that temp table in your main query instead, so your main query's `WHERE` clause now becomes `WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '111111111%'`.

As you've mentioned this is a query from a 3rd party application, there's not much you can do to fix the application's performance without changing the query yourself (obviously not advisable even if possible). Your best bet is to pass along the above information to the vendor and hopefully they're responsive in fixing it.

If you are running the query yourself outside of the application, then you can stage the data from their tables into your own database in a more conducive structure for performance, as my answer mentions above. Then you can run the improved query on your database. There's a multitude of ways you can automated synchronizing the data from the 3rd party database into your own database to accomplish this. Some methodologies involve SQL Jobs, Replication, SSIS, or writing application code to do it. But that's outside the scope of this question, so if you need help with the aforementioned methodologies, feel free to ask a new question regarding them.